# I'm not that bad! Why can't I review?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I saw that there were suggested edits by the indicator by the bar, but when I tried to review I was told that the queue was cleared!

> [image]

I thought that maybe the notification was old, due some caching issues. When I went to the main reviews page, however, I found this:

> [image]

I refreshed both the main review page and the actual suggested edits page six or seven times, but I only got the empty queue page. The number of suggested edits even decreased in that time:

> [image]

I was quite annoyed at this stage, and when I came back *two hours later* the same thing happened!

> [image]

I don't know if caching can be blamed, as other people could review when I couldn't. No matter what is causing it, this is really getting on my nerves. I would be most grateful if it was fixed as soon as possible.

Is anyone else having similar issues?

Comment: Those are most likely reviews that you've skipped.

Comment: Those are may be tag-wiki suggestion, since you [don't have access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)

Comment: I feel a feature-request coming on: Please don't tell me there are reviews available when I don't have enough rep to review them!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are tag wiki and tag wiki excerpt suggestions, suggested by [Jon Arndt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/365152/jon-arndt?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). Those suggestions can only be reviewed by users with 5k reputation.

Since you [don't have enough reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) to review those edits, they are not available for you.

Screenshot for future reference:

> [image: tag wiki suggestion]

Comment: Hmm... I didn't think that _all_ of those might be tag wiki edits. Thanks.

Comment: @BigBadCat Sounds like a feature request - that alert should only provide the number of reviews the user is eligible to work on.

Comment: @Adam Davis Yup. Watch this space.